How can we know the bounds of human capacity to reason?
I wonder if there are ways to quantify our human capacity to reason, and also, whether we can make it relative to some upper bound of reasoning capacity which may exist.
To make the question a little more tangible, think of our progress in speed of transportation over the last three centuries. In 1700s, it took us 6 weeks to sail from New York to London, gradually reducing to today's seven hours of flying. Today we have also developed upper bounds for the speed of transport; practical, and theoretical. A theoretical upper bound is the speed of light, and a practical one is ~30mins via space. Although these bounds change as our understanding of the world evolves, I believe that it is important to have them as guides for direction.
In similar spirit, I wonder, if we have developed frameworks for quantifying our reasoning capacity, and if we have developed handles on estimating "an ultimate reasoning capacity", similar to that upper bound of speed that we have from speed of light.

This mostly looks like a question to psychology.

I was tempted but then I thought that psychology’s scope is the human, and here we shall almost necessarily look beyond humans. Maybe I’m wrong. Core to the question, I think, is: how can we know that we are the most clever pupil in the classroom when our classmates aren’t humans but different species of aliens? And next, how can we know how do we rank in the entire school when we aren’t allowed to leave our classroom? (Class is Earth, school is universe, “we” is humans, alien species in our classroom is the animal and plant kingdoms, aliens in other classrooms are extraterrestrial life forms)

Maybe, since we can’t leave the classroom or communicate with others, we can look at our own evolution of capacity to reason; from prehistory, to ancient, and to today. And/or over our life stages (infant>child>adult). Assuming our today’s capacity the best ever, we ask whether it evolves over eras, and if yes by how much? Extrapolating to the limit of infinite time (future) gives an estimate for our ideal capacity. We shall remember however that the speed of accumulating knowledge doesn’t mean increase in capacity, just as the speed of a car increases but its acceleration remains constant.

Many tests measure capacity only as how much time is needed to solve a given problem, not which problems can be solved. As long as we could solve all problems even if slowly, why care whether we are fastest at solving them? This sounds a lot like bullshit scientology propaganda.

Psychology measures a lot about the mind. There are many tests for memory, for the ability to perform at simple tasks without mistakes, and IQ tests. While their main purpose is to compare humans with each other or in different situations, the also indicate limits.
Computer science on the other hand defines limits to computability, as in which formal problems can be answered at all by computation, which typically is considered vastly superior to human capacity for this kind of issue, and thus serves as an upper boundary. See the Halteproblem as an example. Competitions between humans and computers in games like chess and go also indicate upper limits (whenever a new version of a computer consistently beats humans).
While humans are still considered superior to computers for a range of common-sense problem-solving tasks, it's unclear whether that's just a modelling challenge that will be solved in the future using computers as well.
In any case many experiments show humans proneness to mistakes in thinking and inability to consistently perform in mental tasks without mistake. So reliability of the human mind is not high (compared to computers).
It might also be good to consider this quote attributed to Einstein: “Two things are infinite, the universe and human stupidity, and I am not yet completely sure about the universe.”

You say:

I wonder if there are ways to quantify our human capacity to reason, and also, whether we can make it relative to some upper bound of reasoning capacity which may exist.

And then go on to ask:

How can we know the bounds of human capacity to reason?

One approach is to embrace a naturalized epistemology (SEP) and use scientific discourse to explore what it means to think and reason. Of course, this is related to the fundamental aim of the philosophy of logic. From WP:

Various characterizations of the nature of logic are found in the academic literature. Logic is often seen as the study of the laws of thought, correct reasoning, valid inference, or logical truth. It is a formal science that investigates how conclusions follow from premises in a topic-neutral manner, i.e. independent of the specific subject matter discussed.

So, we can model reason with logic and therefore quantify it. In fact, under the umbrella of experimental philosophy (SEP), we might even consider building a model of human reason on computers and see what comes of it. This is in fact what has traditionally been done in the domain of artificial intelligence (SEP). A classic book in regards to quantifying the human mind is von Neumann's The Computer and the Brain (GB). While outdated, it provides a template for how reason might be understood as a property of the human brain, and how that processing can be quantified. And as von Neumann was big on math, every chapter is loaded with quantification!
As for establishing upward bounds in reasoning, the SEP presents the term bounded rationality (SEP) which admits that all human reason, if modeled quantitatively, can be shown to have upper bounds. From a more empirical perspective, if human reason is modeled as information processing, then like all physical systems of computation (SEP), it must also have upper bounds in the form of physical limits. Of course, there are sorts of descriptions of reason and rationality, and I'd recommend Audi's The Architecture of Reason (GB).

Thank you for the generous amount of pointers J D. Much appreciate it. I need some time to read, digest, and I'll circle back. Shortly after posted my question, it came to me whether we could build such bounds if we built off the concepts and questions that Kahneman presents in his book "Thinking Fast and Slow". It's more behavioral psychology than philosophy, but it's not absurd to use tools from one field to make progress in an other.

Till then, a follow up question wrt naturalized epistemology: Say that I'm a fish and I use the fish equivalent of naturalized epistemology to test my level of reasoning. If I follow it, would I conclude that humans have a higher level of reasoning than I do? (thinking again, do they really?)

The position of naturalized epistemology would absolutely commit you to using cognitive science (I use that as a catch all for cognitive neuroscience, psychology, behavioral economics, etc.) to make and draw conclusions about reasoning. In fact, ethology and hence animal consciousness also provides a comparative framework when discussing "more reasonable". Clearly, a chimp is capable of reasoning to get what they want, and a gorilla taught sign can articulate reasons. I'd suggest a quantitative measure might be imposed from...

the nature of grammar. For instance, the Chomskyan hierarchy provides a good peek into "more" grammar. And if reason is partially understood through the lens of linguistic formal semantics, then reason might have linguistic, mathematical, logical, and algorithmic dimensions.
